# cannot display error messages below form fields

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to display error messages below respective fields and success message below the form. Im able to get the success message but im not getting error messages displayed even the fields are emply. below is my code:-

contact.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {   


 $('#success').html(response);

 //$('#success').hide('slow');
});
return false;


});

});


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateRoleForm() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        if (name == "" || name == null) {
            $('#errortext1').html('please enter name.'); 
            return false;
        }
        else if{
        var name = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if (name == "" || name == null) {
            $('#errortext2').html('please enter email.'); 
            return false;
        }
        else if{
        var name = document.getElementById('message').value;
        if (name == "" || name == null) {
            $('#errortext3').html('please enter message.'); 
            return false;
        }
        else {
        $('#success').html('Mail sent'); 
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="mycontactform" class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Contact Us</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
        </li>
        <li id="name">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name"  name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
        <br><small class="errorText"></small></br>
        <div id="errorText1" style="color:red;"> </div>

        </li>
        <li id="email">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
            <br><small class="errorText"></small></br>
            <div id="errorText2" style="color:red;"></div>
        </li>

        <li id="message">
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"  cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
            <br><small class="errorText"></small></br>
            <div id="errorText3" style="color:red;"></div>
        </li>
<li>
            <input type="button"  class="submit" style="width:70px; text-align:center; height:30px; margin-left:200px; cursor:pointer"  value="SEND" id="submit" onclick="return validateRoleForm()"/>


        </li><div id="success" style="color:red;"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

send.php

```
<?php

// Here we get all the information from the fields sent over by the form.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = 'babloopuneeth@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
    $headers = 'From: youremail@domain.com' . "\r\n";


  $error  = array(
    "name"    =>  "",
    "email"   =>  "",
    "message" =>  ""
  );

  json_encode($error);

  $email  = ( isset( $_POST["email"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["email"] ) : false;
  $name   = ( isset( $_POST["name"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["name"] ) : false;
  $message  = ( isset( $_POST["message"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["message"] ) : false;

  if ( !$email ) {
    $error["email"] = "Email is required!";
  }
  if ( !$name ) {
    $error["name"] = "Name is required!";
  }
  if ( !$message ) {
    $error["message"] = "Message is required!";
  }



else { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
    echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}

?>
```

Please help me out. Im nt getting where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry that code doesn't make sense, you should put the `isset` logic on the top and get ride of those variables that aren't checked.

Answer (score 0):

your `json_encode` is called before you actually set the error messages, and secondly your not echoing the json_encode result

Answer (score 0):

You're not echoing the error messages anywhere in your script. You'll have to set the error messages first, and then echo them after validating the form inputs.

I'd store those error messages in an array, and then use a foreach loop to display them in a list.

```
if ( !$email ) {
  $error[] = "Email is required!";
}
if ( !$name ) {
  $error[] = "Name is required!";
}
if ( !$message ) {
  $error[] = "Message is required!";
}
```

And in your `index.php`:

```
foreach($error as $e) {
echo "<li>$e</li>";
}
```

Also, I suggesting putting the isset on the top of the script. Add a `name` attribute to your submit button, first:

and then, you can check if the form was submitted, with `isset()`:

```
if( isset($_POST['mySubmitButton']) ) { 

//rest of the code here

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But it is not displaying below the fields?

Comment: @PuneethP: you'll need to add the foreach in your error statement `<div>`.

Comment: You need to insert the `foreach` loop *inside* the `<div>` in which you're planning to show the errors in. Not sure if this is the best practice but you can do something like: `<div id="errorDisplay"> foreach($error as $e) { echo $e; } </div>`. You can style the div however you want. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to return `false` each time when you have encountered an error for each field like

```
if( typeof response["email"] != "undefined" ) {
    $("li#email .errorText").html(response["email"]);
    return false;
}
```

You need to do this for each field,And also you can check with

```
if(response["email"] && response["email"].trim() != '')
```

It is better that you need to trace validation on the page itself through the javascript and after it validated then you can goto that pag to process data.Its my advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="email">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
            <br><small class="errorText"></small></br>
            <div id="errorText" style="color:red;"></div>
        </li>
change to 
<li id="email">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
            <br><small class="errorText"></small></br>
            <div id="errorText1" style="color:red;"></div>
        </li>
give different id for different fields
ans use simple java script as 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateRoleForm() {
        var name = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if (name == "" || name == null) {
            $('#errortext1').html('please enter email.');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>


change 
<input type="button"  class="submit" style="width:70px; text-align:center; height:30px; margin-left:200px; cursor:pointer"  value="SEND" id="submit" />
to 
<input type="button"  class="submit" style="width:70px; text-align:center; height:30px; margin-left:200px; cursor:pointer" id="submit" onclick = "return validateRoleForm()" />
```

Comment: what is that 'RoleName'?

Comment: y is tat ?>'); after please enter mail??

Comment: please add different -2 id for each error msg like errortext2 for name

Comment: check answer again ,,

Comment: hey i even want the success message to be dispalyed if the message is sent and page should be refreshed

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        if (name == "" || name == null) {
            $('#errortext1').html('please enter name.'); 
            return false;
        }
        else if{
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if (email == "" || email == null) {
            $('#errortext2').html('please enter email.'); 
            return false;
        }
        else if{
        var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
        if (message == "" || message == null) {
            $('#errortext3').html('please enter message.'); 
            return false;
        }
        else {
         return true;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="mycontactform" class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Contact Us</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
        </li>
        <li id="name">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name"  name="name" placeholder="John Doe"/>
        <br><small class="errorText"></small></br>
        <div id="errorText1" style="color:red;"></div>

        </li>
        <li id="email">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
            <br><small class="errorText"></small></br>
            <div id="errorText2" style="color:red;"></div>
        </li>

        <li id="message">
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"  cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
            <br><small class="errorText"></small></br>
            <div id="errorText3" style="color:red;"></div>
        </li>
<li>
            <input type="button"  class="submit" id="submit" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this jQuery Plugin:

http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/